# Ruby, avoid return value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, return-value

I just added logger function in my model:

```
 def self.encrypt(pass, salt)
    logger.debug "--> user##encrypt"
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(pass+salt)
    logger.debug "user##encrypt <--"
  end
```

What's happening now ?
Simply the method doesen't work anymore because the last value is a debug string!!
Is there anyway to make the last line trasparent and to still return the previous one, but passing by the previous line anyway ?
P.S I can't move the debug line and I don't want to use any other ways to track the application flow

Answer (score 3):

everything in ruby is an expression, so everything must have a return value. I would do it like this

```
def self.encrypt(pass, salt)
  logger.debug "--> user##encrypt"
  sha = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(pass+salt)
  logger.debug "user##encrypt <--"
  return sha
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def self.encrypt(pass, salt)
  logger.debug "--> user##encrypt"
  hex = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(pass+salt)
  logger.debug "user##encrypt <--"
  hex
end
```